# как найти конкретное слово, проверить на наличие в словаре и если есть, заменить его на значение из словаря и написать его в другом файле

Tags: python

я хочу сделать так, чтобы скрипт искал ключевые слова, которые начинаются с `shortkey="` из какого либо другого файла, затем проверял на наличие такого слова в словаре, и если имеется, то брал значения данного слова из словаря и вставлял их в другой файл. мой код ниже почему то не работает...

также как мне сделать так, чтобы уже написанные значения во втором файле не повторялись? т.е. если уже есть `goodmorning` в `newfile.txt`, то не переписывать его во второй раз.

```
keyword = {
      "shortkey":"longer sentence",
      "gm":"goodmorning",
      "etc":"etcetera"
}

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
   with open('newfile.txt', 'a') as newfile:
      lines = file.readlines()
      for line in lines:
         if 'shortkey="' in line:
            x = line.split('"')[1].split()
            if x == keyword.keys():
               for x, replacement in keyword.items():
                 newfile.write(replacement)
```

внутри файла `file.txt`:

```
shortkey="gm gm gm etc shortkey novalue"
```

Ожидаемый output в файле `newfile.txt`:

```
goodmorning etcetera longer sentence
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

keywords = {
      "shortkey":"longer sentence",
      "gm":"goodmorning",
      "etc":"etcetera"
}

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    with open('newfile.txt', 'a') as newfile:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            # поиск всех совпадений
            matches = re.findall(r"shortkey=\"(.*?)\"", line)
            for match in matches:
                words = match.split()
                for word in words:
                    # если такой ключ IN словаре (не "==", как это было у вас в примере)
                    if word in keywords.keys():
                        newfile.write(keywords[word] + " ")
```

Этот вариант запишет в файл "*goodmorning goodmorning goodmorning etcetera longer sentence*"

Если вам нужно убрать дубликаты, сначала записывайте все значение в set, а только потом пишите их в файл.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно избавиться от дубликатов, да еще и сохранить порядок следования слов, то тогда вот так:

```
import collections

keyword = {
      "shortkey":"longer sentence",
      "gm":"goodmorning",
      "etc":"etcetera"
}

with open('001.txt', 'r') as file:
     lines = file.readlines()

with open('newfile.txt', 'a') as newfile:
    for line in lines:
        if 'shortkey' in line:
            words = collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(line.split('=')[1].split()[1:-1]) 
            for word in words:
                res = keyword.get(word, word)
                print(res, file=newfile, end=' ')
```

> goodmorning etcetera longer sentence

Если порядок слов не важен, то тогда всё еще проще:

```
keyword = {
      "shortkey":"longer sentence",
      "gm":"goodmorning",
      "etc":"etcetera"
}

with open('001.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

with open('newfile.txt', 'a') as newfile:
    for line in lines:
        if 'shortkey' in line:
            words = set(line.split('=')[1].split()[1:-1])
            for word in words:
                res = keyword.get(word, word)
                print(res, file=newfile, end=' ')
```

> longer sentence etcetera goodmorning

Обратите внимание на строку `keyword.get(word, word)` - она будет либо менять на выходе значение исходного слова на слово из словаря, либо оставлять исходное слово и записывать его в newfile.txt , если в словаре не будет найдена замена.